# Javascript: BitAnd function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if we have BitAnd operation in javascript?Do we have one?Just like in oracle.I tried to find in google ,I couldn`t find.Please suggest if better function we have for that.

Comment: Do you mean simple bitwise `and`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is such a operator: `&`.

```
var c = a & b;
```

For more information have a look at the [respective MDN article on bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Comment: Sirko:Is this same as BITAND in oracle?I mean it`s functionality.

Comment: @user1495475 Judging from [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions014.htm): Yes.